# Converting rdd to dataframe: AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'toDF' using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert the RDD to DataFrame using PySpark. Below is my code.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Dataframe_examples")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

def parsedLine(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    movieId = fields[0]
    movieName = fields[1]
    genres = fields[2]
    return movieId, movieName, genres

movies = sc.textFile("file:///home/ajit/ml-25m/movies.csv")
parsedLines = movies.map(parsedLine)
print(parsedLines.count())

dataFrame = parsedLines.toDF(["movieId"])
dataFrame.printSchema()
```

I am running this code using PyCharm IDE.

And I get the error:

```
File "/home/ajit/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Dataframe_examples.py", line 19, in <module>
    dataFrame = parsedLines.toDF(["movieId"])
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'toDF'
```

As I am new to this, let me know what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize **`SparkSession`** by passing **sparkcontext**.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Dataframe_examples")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession(sc)

def parsedLine(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    movieId = fields[0]
    movieName = fields[1]
    genres = fields[2]
    return movieId, movieName, genres

movies = sc.textFile("file:///home/ajit/ml-25m/movies.csv")

#or using spark.sparkContext
movies = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///home/ajit/ml-25m/movies.csv")

parsedLines = movies.map(parsedLine)
print(parsedLines.count())

dataFrame = parsedLines.toDF(["movieId"])
dataFrame.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SparkSession` to make the RDD dataframe as follows:

```
movies = sc.textFile("file:///home/ajit/ml-25m/movies.csv")
parsedLines = movies.map(parsedLine)
print(parsedLines.count())

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(parsedLines).toDF(["movieId"])
dataFrame.printSchema()
```

or use the spark context from the session at first.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Dataframe_examples").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
```